# Slide the whole screen of your app that uses UITabbarController as rootcontroller

Tags: ios, menu, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a tabbarcontroller in my app with several viewcontrollers inside it, just normal standard stuff. Lately I need to add the ability to slide the whole screen when I click a button from my content view.

This is what my appdelegate does:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window.root = self.tabBarController; //tabBarController is IBOutlet to the tabbar
}
```

And in one of my viewcontroller I do this:

```
- (IBAction)filterButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut  | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        //slide everything to the right?
        self.navigationController.view = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(260.0f, 0.0f);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       //do something, possibly show the view that comes up from the left 
    }];
```

You might ask why does the button needs to be inside the contentview, well because my apps want to be designed that way I guess?

Now, the content of the tab bar does slide but not the tab bar below, I know it's because the self.navigationController.view is for the contentview inside the tab bar.

I've been trying to find a way to slide/animate the whole thing but from inside the contentview is it possible to get to the root?

What's your suggestion to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it will help with the animation but you can get your controller with something like `((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).window.root` ... adjusted for whatever class name you're actually using for your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your tab bar controller view from any VC inside using

```
self.tabBarController.view
```

Then just animate that view.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. Btw I noticed that your window can only have one root view/controller. If I already have tabbarcontroller in my window and I need to slide the tabbar view so it reveals the menu. What do you think it's the best way to add the slide menu view/controller?

Comment: There are a lot of implementations of such a thing, e.g. https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController. Basically, you have a headless root view controller that acts as a container for menu and tabbar controllers. Then you slide between them using VC containment methods.